# Adding new custom permissions in Django

Tags: django, django-south, django-permissions

I am using custom permissions in my Django models like this:

```
class T21Turma(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        permissions = (("can_view_boletim", "Can view boletim"),
                       ("can_view_mensalidades", "Can view mensalidades"),)
```

The problem is that when I add a permission to the list it doesn't get added to the `auth_permission` table when I run syncdb. What am I doing wrong. If it makes any difference I am using south for database migrations.

Comment: You can fix the field length in the Permissions model:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/28343007/3310666

Answer (score 60, accepted):

South does not track django.contrib.auth permissions.  See [ticket #211](http://south.aeracode.org/ticket/211) for more information.

One of the comments on the ticket suggests that using the `--all` option on syncdb may solve the problem.

Comment: Sounds like exactly my problem except that I can't get the --all switch to work with syncdb nor do I find the switch documented anywhere.

Comment: This worked after I upgraded to south 0.6.2 (I was running 0.5) previously.

Comment: This just gives me the error "DatabaseError: value too long for type character varying(50)"

Comment: that means you have a value already in the DB that is longer than 50 chars.

Comment: @Cerin - I got that when my permission description was over 50 characters. Seems a likely place to make that mistake.

Answer (score 48):

If you want "manage.py migrate" to do everything (without calling syncdb --all). You need to create new permissions with a migration:

```
user@host> manage.py datamigration myapp add_perm_foo --freeze=contenttypes --freeze=auth
```

Edit the created file:

```
class Migration(DataMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        "Write your forwards methods here."
        ct, created = orm['contenttypes.ContentType'].objects.get_or_create(
            model='mymodel', app_label='myapp') # model must be lowercase!
        perm, created = orm['auth.permission'].objects.get_or_create(
            content_type=ct, codename='mymodel_foo', defaults=dict(name=u'Verbose Name'))
```

Comment: there is no need for last three lines, `defaults` keyword argument of `get_or_create` can be used instead [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get_or_create)

Comment: If you're using this method you need to add the options `--freeze=contenttypes --freeze=auth` to the datamigration command. Otherwise you'll get the error @balmaster mentions below.

E.g: `manage.py datamigration myapp add_perm_foo --freeze=contenttypes --freeze=auth`

Answer (score 27):

This worked for me:

```
./manage.py update_permissions
```

It is a [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) thing.

Comment: "DatabaseError: value too long for type character varying(50)". The cause is my permission's name was too long, but that's a horribly unhelpful error message, especially when I'm adding dozens of new permissions.

Answer (score 20):

You can connect to the `post_migrate` signal in order to update the permissions after migration. I use the following code, slightly modified from [Dev with Passion](http://devwithpassion.com/felipe/south-django-permissions/) and originally from [django-extensions](http://packages.python.org/django-extensions/).

```
# Add to your project-level __init__.py

from south.signals import post_migrate

def update_permissions_after_migration(app,**kwargs):
    """
    Update app permission just after every migration.
    This is based on app django_extensions update_permissions management command.
    """
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.db.models import get_app, get_models
    from django.contrib.auth.management import create_permissions

    create_permissions(get_app(app), get_models(), 2 if settings.DEBUG else 0)

post_migrate.connect(update_permissions_after_migration)
```

Comment: This has an issue when working with something like gunicorn to run the app, namely it fails at finding environmental variable that is set in the wsgi.py file.

Answer (score 2):

When i runnning migration with following code

```
ct, created = orm['contenttypes.ContentType'].objects.get_or_create(model='mymodel',     app_label='myapp') # model must bei lowercase!
perm, created = orm['auth.permission'].objects.get_or_create(content_type=ct, codename='mymodel_foo')
```

I getting folloving error

```
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\south-0.7.3-py2.6.egg\south\orm.py", line 170, in  __getitem__
raise KeyError("The model '%s' from the app '%s' is not available in this migration." % (model, app))
KeyError: "The model 'contenttype' from the app 'contenttypes' is not available in this migration."
```

To prevent this error, i modified the code

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission

class Migration(DataMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        "Write your forwards methods here."
        ct = ContentType.objects.get(model='mymodel', app_label='myapp') 
        perm, created = Permission.objects.get_or_create(content_type=ct, codename='mymodel_foo')
        if created:
            perm.name=u'my permission description'
            perm.save()
```

Comment: Bad idea; you should use the frozen ORM. Add `--freeze=contenttypes --freeze=auth` to your `./manage.py datamigration` command line.