# mysql exception when synchronizing db with django's manage.py script

Tags: django, django-models

I am relatively new to django. I have defined my db schema and validated it  with no errors (manage.py validate reports 0 errors found).

Yet when I run ./manage.py syncdb

I get the following stack trace:

```
Creating table demo_foobar_one
Creating table demo_foobar_two
<snip>...</snip>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 218, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 347, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 103, in handle_noargs
    emit_post_sync_signal(created_models, verbosity, interactive, db)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 185, in emit_post_sync_signal
    interactive=interactive, db=db)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 162, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 28, in create_permissions
    defaults={'name': name, 'content_type': ctype})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 135, in get_or_create
    return self.get_query_set().get_or_create(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 373, in get_or_create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 435, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 528, in save_base
    result = manager._insert(values, return_id=update_pk, using=using)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 195, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, values, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1479, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 783, in execute_sql
    cursor = super(SQLInsertCompiler, self).execute_sql(None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 727, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 15, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 86, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 176, in execute
    if not self._defer_warnings: self._warning_check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 92, in _warning_check
    warn(w[-1], self.Warning, 3)
_mysql_exceptions.Warning: Data truncated for column 'name' at row 1
```

I have checked (and double checked) my table schema. All name field are CharField type with maximum length = 64. The backend db I am using is MySQL, so I am sure that indexes can be created for strings of length 64.

What could be causing this error (I suspect it is a misleading error message - even though its coming from the db itself)...

Comment: Post your Models too. This would help us.

Comment: [You can fix the field length in the Permissions model][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28343007/3310666

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The traceback is happening during the creation of a `django.contrib.auth.Permission`: some of these get created for your models automatically as part of `syncdb`.

`Permission.name` has `max_length=50`, so you probably have an application and/or model class with a really long name?

Try the following query in `manage.py dbshell`:

```
SELECT * FROM auth_permission WHERE LENGTH(name) = 50;
```

If you cannot change your model name, then you can fix this problem by reducing the length of the generated `Permission.name` by specifying `verbose_name` in the model Meta class (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#verbose-name) for more details):

```
class MyVeryLongModelNameThatIsBreakingMyMigration(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'my long model'
```

### Update

There's an open (as of 2013) Django ticket to fix this:

- [#8162 (Increase Permission.name max_length)](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8162)

Comment: brilliant diagnosis!. How did you work out that the exception was being thrown during the creation of django.contrib.auth.Permission ? (I cant see that in the stack trace). In any case, I run the SQL statement you suggested (one row was returned), and indeed I saw that one of the model names has been truncated. How may I fix this?

Comment: The stacktrace references this code:  http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py#L28 , which is creating an object in the Permission model, belonging to the auth application (and thus the auth_permission table).

Comment: Right: reading the function names, `create_permissions` stands out. Unfortunately, there's no real way to fix this except to shorten the affected name: a Django bug should probably be filed, to increase the name length and/or implement hashing of the excess.

Comment: I have inherited some code with this same problem. I cannot use syncdb to create a database because some of the model names are too long. The frustrating part is that these same models are working in production, so

Answer (score 3):

As [Piet Delport](https://stackoverflow.com/users/444705/piet-delport) noted, [the problem is that your model name is too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877286/mysql-exception-when-synchronizing-db-with-djangos-manage-py-script/3877444#3877444).

You're certainly going to have to shorten your model name, and then clean up your database.  How you do that depends upon where you are in the development process.

- If this is a brand new application, with a dedicated database, and no actual data, the simple answer is to drop and recreate the database, and then re-run `python manage.py syncdb`.
- If you have other tables in the database that need to be left alone, but the tables for your Django have no 'real' data, and can thus be dropped without damage, then you can use `manage.py sqlclear` to generate SQL DDL to drop all of the Django-generated tables, constraints, and indexes.

  Do the following:

  ```
  apps="auth contenttypes sessions sites messages admin <myapp1> <myapp2>"
  python manage.py sqlclear ${apps} > clear.sql
  ```

  You can feed the generated script to `mysql` or `python manage.py dbshell`.  Once that's done, you can re-run `python manage.py syncdb`.
- If you have actual data in your database tables that can't be dropped or deleted: **Slap yourself** and repeat 100 times **"I will never do development against a production database again.  I will always back up my databases before changing them."**  Now you're going to have to hand-code SQL to change the affected table name, as well as anything else that references it **and** any references in the `auth_permissions` table and any other Django system tables.  Your actual steps will depend entirely upon the state of your database and tables.

Comment: Thanks for the advice (I am not working on a production db BTW ;) ). I had already done what you suggested -(from Piers post), before you posted it. But thanks for your help anyhow. I would vote your answer up, as it at least confirmed what I did - but I am prevented from doing so (asking for a login)

Comment: I know this is old, but why is dropping of any tables necessary when the only thing that we change is the verbose name? I would assume that a manual update of a couple of truncated name fields would do it without dropping anything as this doesn't affect any ids / codename.

PS You assume that if someone has data they don't want to lose in a production database it means they're developing directly on that environment. This is 9/10 times not the case, people eventually launch their projects and care about data and this is why we use migration tools and not syncdb.

Answer (score 1):

I also got error like this one using postgresql django 1.2, but the problem was not the length, but using `ugettext_lazy` for translating the names. `('can_purge', _("Can purge"))` is evidently unacceptable, since the name is stored in the database as text