# heroku and django, value too long for type character varying(50)

Tags: django, heroku

I get this error on syncdb:

```
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 203, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1576, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 910, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 40, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 52, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: value too long for type character varying(50)
```

After create this new model:

```
class Promocio(models.Model):
    codiIdioma = models.CharField(u"Codi de l'idioma",max_length = 10, choices = LANGUAGES, unique=True  )    
    headTxt = models.TextField( u"Text del títol",   help_text = u'''Text que apareixerà com a títol al missatge de promoció de la recollida de e-mails amb la tablet''' )
    bodyTxt = models.TextField( u"Text del cost del missatge" ,  help_text = u'''Text que apareixerà com al cos del missatge de promoció de la recollida de e-mails amb la tablet''')
    buttonTxt =  models.TextField( u"Text del butó d'OK",  help_text = u'''Text que apareixerà dins el butó de recollida de e-mails amb la tablet''' )
    codiOrdenacio = models.CharField(u"Codi d'ordenació",max_length = 10, blank = True, help_text = u"Codi alfanumèric per determinar quin idioma es presenta abans i quin després. Ex: 00AA" )  

    class Meta:
        ordering=['codiOrdenacio']
        db_table = u'promocions_tablet'
        verbose_name = u'Missatge de Promoció a mostrar a la tablet'
        verbose_name_plural = u'Missatges de Promoció a mostrar a la tablet'
```

Some ideas to fix this?

Comment: Do you have an `initial_data` fixture?

Comment: [You can fix the field length in the Permissions model][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28343007/3310666

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only objects that are created automatically during `syncdb` are `ContentType`s, but every char field on `ContentType` allows 100 characters, and has since the earliest days of Django. The `verbose_name` is used for the `name` field on the contenttype, but your `verbose_name`, while long, is still under even 50 chars.

Short of that, Django also processes any `initial_data` fixtures in *all* apps every time `syncdb` is run. That's why I asked if you had any. If there's none for this particular app, there must be some app, *somewhere* that does have one. Additionally, this can include third-party apps listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`, so you might have some looking around to do.

Comment: I have changed versose names to a more shorted one and now runs. Thanks Chris to put me on solution's way.

Comment: There are also [contrib.auth permissions](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.1/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L66) which allow max 50 chars for their names.