# Strange PostgreSQL "value too long for type character varying(500)"

Tags: sql, database, django, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a Postgres schema which looks like:

[image]

The problem is that whenever I save text longer than 500 characters in the description column I get the error:

```
value too long for type character varying(500)
```

In the documentation for Postgres it says type text can have unlimited characters.

I'm using postgresql-9.1.

This table has been generated using Django 1.4 and the field type in the model is TextField, if that helps explain the problem further.

Any ideas as why this is happening and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django fixture fails, stating "DatabaseError: value too long for type character varying(50)"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803552/django-fixture-fails-stating-databaseerror-value-too-long-for-type-character)

Comment: Does the issue occur with psql inserts, or only from django?

Comment: Since you've generated the table from a Django model, how about showing your Django model code?

Comment: I just checked the psql insert through command line the error doesn't occur there. It might be an encoding problem.

Comment: Is it possible that this column was character varying(500), but has been changed to text, but the change hasn't been committed, and so the django client can't see the change?  That seems unlikely, but the error from django definitely indicates that for it, the column is char var, while we clearly see from this output that it is text.

Comment: No, it is not an encoding problem. Please show the actual INSERT statement generated by Django, and the full, exact text of the error message. You can get both from the PostgreSQL log files.

Comment: I just checked the log file the error was being occurred when a related field was being saved, which wasn't abiding by the 500 char constraint

Comment: Glad to hear you have a solution. Now you know one more thing to check, and one more thing to include in future questions :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, introduced me to a very handy piece of knowledge for tracing bugs.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

By specifying the column as `VARCHAR(500)`  you've set an explicit 500 character limit. You might not have done this yourself explicitly, but Django has done it for you somewhere. Telling you where is hard when you haven't shown your model, the full error text, or the query that produced the error.

If you don't want one, use an unqualified `VARCHAR`, or use the `TEXT` type.

`varchar` and `text` are limited in length only by the system limits on column size - about 1GB - and by your memory. However, adding a length-qualifier to `varchar` sets a smaller limit manually. All of the following are largely equivalent:

```
column_name VARCHAR(500)

column_name VARCHAR CHECK (length(column_name) <= 500) 

column_name TEXT CHECK (length(column_name) <= 500)
```

The only differences are in how database metadata is reported and which SQLSTATE is raised when the constraint is violated.

The length constraint is not generally obeyed in prepared statement parameters, function calls, etc, as shown:

```
regress=> \x
Expanded display is on.
regress=> PREPARE t2(varchar(500)) AS SELECT $1;
PREPARE
regress=> EXECUTE t2( repeat('x',601) );
-[ RECORD 1 ]-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
?column? | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

and in explicit casts it result in truncation:

```
regress=> SELECT repeat('x',501)::varchar(1);
-[ RECORD 1 ]
repeat | x
```

so I think you *are* using a `VARCHAR(500)` column, and you're looking at the wrong table or wrong instance of the database.

Comment: I'm using type text look at the description column

Comment: @Parham I see that. The explanation remains relevant; `varchar(500)` is being used somewhere. Please show the actual query in your question so we can see the query that's failing. If you can't get it from Django, get it from the PostgreSQL log files and edit your question to add the query to the question. You might need to set `log_statement = 'all'` in `postgresql.conf` and reload PostgreSQL if the full query text isn't logged alongside the error.

Comment: I just checked the log files as you suggested it turns out that the error was occurring when another related field was being saved

Comment: Can't emphasize enough that TEXT has a limit that is smaller than VARCHAR(1024), at least for Redshift. You will still run into size problems with TEXT without being able to tweak character length, where as varchar can be tweaked.

Comment: @deesolie Redshift *is not PostgreSQL*, you can't expect it to behave like PostgreSQL. It's a mostly-postgres-compatible frontend on a totally different database engine.

Comment: That's why I said "at least for Redshift" in case other users came across this that use Redshift. I know I did at least. But good to call out that Postgres != Redshift, even though Redshift is based on Postgres

Answer (score 19):

Character varying is different than text.  Try running

```
ALTER TABLE product_product ALTER COLUMN code TYPE text;
```

That will change the column type to text, which is limited to some very large amount of data (you would probably never actually hit it.)

Comment: I edited the question, the problem is with the description field which is already type text

Comment: Can't emphasize enough that TEXT has a limit that is smaller than VARCHAR(1024), at least for Redshift. You will still run into size problems with TEXT without being able to tweak character length, where as varchar can be tweaked.

Answer (score 7):

We had this same issue. We solved it adding 'length' to entity attribute definition:

```
@Column(columnDefinition="text", length=10485760)
private String configFileXml = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had Data in Table , So PostgreSQL don't allow me to Make changes on my table !

change it to bigger value !

Comment: you must have deleted all data first then. right? show here how to delete them all. Well done

Comment: you are nothing ...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For my case, I went to pgAdmin>Schemas>Tables>`blog_post` and then arrow click to 'Colums' then found **the colum, character varing(25)**. right click and then properties, click 'Definition. Finally I saw 'Length/Precision'. I changed 25 to 50. That's it. All good.

---

Once again, you need to change the size of your colum. go to pgAdmin>Schemas>Tables>(your app_model name)>Colums>(the colum you have problem)>Definition>Length
Change the size bigger. That's it!!!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Adding to answer by [Scot S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1269609/scott-s) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13485060/8926214).

---

For Django [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#imagefield) or [FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#filefield),

adding max_length in the models.py worked for me.

```
img1 = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path,**max_length=500**)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

migrated a

```
CharField(max_length=1) to CharField(max_length=2)
```

then save some data.
Then I wanna migrate back

DB already have data like `"sg"` inside.

just temporarily make them shorter will fix this error

Note if you have `django-simple-history` installed. got there and change/delete data as well

*The error log didn't show what table/field, but the `varying(1)` indicate where you should go.*