# How to increase default variable length in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, amazon-redshift, string-length

Is there a way to increase default variable length in Python (I think default is 255 for string ?) ? For example in SAS there is a length statement to assign a fixed length to a certain variable. It works like- LENGTH variable-list $ number-of-bytes;

The reason I want to do that is this error:

```
DataError: value too long for type character varying(256)
```

I am trying to write a pandas data frame to redshift but its not working because of the above error. Now I have almost 400 variables/columns, most of them are string type (basically description or comments) and its not possible to check each variable to find the problem. Also a point to be noted is pandas data frame is considering those string or varchar type columns as 'object' type.

I have tried to search the issue, but not seeing much information.

Comment: It's not to do with Python - if you've specified in redshift that 256 is the limit - it's going to enforce that constraint. You can either truncate your string before loading it or run an `alter table` constraint if the 256 isn't sufficient.

Comment: Do you think - this might work to increase the length ? data.to_sql(name="table", con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False,
            dtype={'col1': sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR(length=3000), 
                   'col2': sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR(length=3000),
                   'col3': sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR(length=3000) }  )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're encountering is a limit set in your Redshift schema, not in python or pandas. Redshift is based on PostgreSQL, so you may find [the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485030/strange-postgresql-value-too-long-for-type-character-varying500) to be useful.