# django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(1)

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my Django application to Heroku and I need to migrate a database to create tables, but it's giving me an error, I understand that it's an error with fields and max_length, but I don't have any fields with (1) max length:

```
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.StringDataRightTruncation: value too long for type character varying(1)


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 245, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 106, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 487, in add_field
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 142, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(1)
```

My models don't have any fields with max_length=1, it's all working locally on my machine with SQLite but on Postgres, it gives an error:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    calories = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'id:{self.id}, {self.name}, price:{self.price}, cals:{self.calories}'


class RecipeItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    
    grams = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def get_total(self):
        total = (self.product.price / 100) * self.grams
        return total

    def __str__(self):
        return f'id:{self.id}'

class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(RecipeItem, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    
    @property
    def get_total_price(self):
        recipeitems = self.items.all()
        total = sum([item.get_total for item in recipeitems])
        return total

    @property
    def get_total_calories(self):
        recipeitems = self.items.all()
        total = int(sum([(item.product.calories / 100) * item.grams for item in recipeitems]))
        return total

    def get_products(self):
        return "\n".join([p.products for p in self.product.all()])

    def __str__(self):
        return f'id:{self.id}, {self.name}, price:{self.get_total_price}, cals:{self.get_total_calories}'


class Plan(models.Model):
    PLAN_DAYS_CHOICES = [
        ('3d', '3-day plan'),
        ('7d', '7-day plan'),
    ]
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=PLAN_DAYS_CHOICES)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, max_length=255)

    @property
    def get_total_items(self):
        planitems = self.planitem_set.all()
        total = planitems.count()
        return total

    @property
    def get_total_price(self):
        planitems = self.planitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.recipe.get_total_price for item in planitems])
        return total

    @property
    def get_total_calories(self):
        planitems = self.planitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.recipe.get_total_calories for item in planitems])
        return total

    def __str__(self):
        return f'id:{self.id}, {self.type}, owner:{self.user.username}'



class PlanItem(models.Model):
    DAYS_CHOICES = [
        ('1', 'Day 1'),
        ('2', 'Day 2'),
        ('3', 'Day 3'),
        ('4', 'Day 4'),
        ('5', 'Day 5'),
        ('6', 'Day 6'),
        ('7', 'Day 7'),
    ]
    TIME_CHOICES = [
        ('br', 'Breakfast'),
        ('ln', 'Lunch'),
        ('dn', 'Dinner'),
        ('sn', 'Snack'),
    ]

    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    plan = models.ForeignKey(Plan, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    day = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=DAYS_CHOICES)
    time = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=TIME_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return f'id:{self.id} recipe under plan id:{self.plan.id}'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485030/strange-postgresql-value-too-long-for-type-character-varying500 its has solution here.

Comment: @SivaSankar i can't find an answer here, I can't find a problem field and not sure how to do it, I'm a beginner.

Comment: max_length=255 means varchar(50), django does this directly.

Comment: @SivaSankar but I'm getting an error about varchar(1) as I see in logs. I don't know what field it can be.

Comment: fastest way to see on which table this dango error occurs is to search the model names in the error. In your case its the Plan model. Are the above error you provided are heroku logs? NEVER run makemigrations on heroku. Run > heroku run python manage.py migrate

Comment: @SivaSankar Yes, this error is from Heroku, I tried your command but it gave me the same error.

Comment: did you run > heroku run python manage.py makmigrations before?

Comment: @SivaSankar yes, I think so.

Comment: Ok. just delete the heroku postgresql instance and create new one. Then in your heroku app settings make sure that you have connected with new heroku postgresql package. Then only run > heroku run python manage.py migrate after deploying. Here, this would help in deleting and creating new postgresql instance in heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql