# Adding Custom Permissions in django.auth.models

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I want to add some different custom permissions in django's user model.
I want to add:

```
Class Meta:
    permissions = (
        ("view_user", "Can see available users"),
        ("export_user", "Can Download the list of all users"),
    )
```

How can I achieve this?
Kindly help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your own custom permission class using built in feature [PermissionsMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-permissions)

Answer (score 0):

How you are creating database?

You should use `south` with `-all` method.

http://south.aeracode.org/

I have also find connected topic:
[Adding new custom permissions in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742021/adding-new-custom-permissions-in-django)